# Converting in-line URLs and e-mail addresses into links in Java

Tags: java, regex, text

Consider a string which contains unstructured plain text (no HTML) which sometimes include URLs and e-mail addresses. I want to convert all URLs and e-mail addresses in this string into HTML links pointing to the respective URLs and e-mail addresses (mailto-links).

What is the best way and most general way to solve this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author Sebastian Sdorra
 */
public class TokenTextParser
{
  private static final Pattern REGEX_URL =
    Pattern.compile(
        "\\(?\\b((?:https?://|ftps?://|mailto:|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|])");

  private static final String REPLACE_URL =
    "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{1}\">{0}</a>";

  public String parseText(String content)
  {
    Matcher m = REGEX_URL.matcher(content);
    List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
    int position = 0;
    String tokenContent = null;

    while (m.find())
    {
      int start = m.start();
      int end = m.end();
      String replacement = m.group();

      if (replacement.startsWith("www"))
      {
        replacement = "http://" + replacement;
      }

      tokenContent = content.substring(position, start);
      tokens.add(new Token(tokenContent));
      tokenContent = content.substring(start, end);
      tokens.add(new Token(tokenContent, replacement));
      position = end;
    }

    tokenContent = content.substring(position, content.length());
    tokens.add(new Token(tokenContent));

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    for (Token token : tokens)
    {
      if (token.getReplacement() != null)
      {
        buffer.append(MessageFormat.format(REPLACE_URL, token.getValue(),
                                           token.getReplacement()));
      }
      else
      {
        buffer.append(token.getValue().replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">",
                "&gt;"));
      }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
  }

  private static class Token
  {

    public Token(String value)
    {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public Token(String value, String replacement)
    {
      this.value = value;
      this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    public String getReplacement()
    {
      return replacement;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
      return value;
    }

    private String replacement;
    private String value;
  }
}
```